# Design pattern for API with type identifier that determines what downstream services to call

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have an endpoint, let's call it "GetPersonInfo". GetPersonInfo is given a few parameters but one of them is "PersonType". Based on this PersonType, multiple downstream services are called. Some of these services could be shared between PersonType's but that is not a guarantee.

For example GetPersonInfo(...) #1:
PersonType = "Adult"

When GetPersonInfo is called for Adult, the API endpoint would need to make two downstream calls and populate the payload model with results:
"GetPersonName()" and "GetFavoriteAlcoholicBeverage()"

For example GetPersonInfo(...) #2:
PersonType = "Child"

When GetPersonInfo is called for Child, the api endpoint would need to make two downstream calls and populate the payload model with results:
"GetPersonName()" and "GetFavoriteToy()"

For example GetPersonInfo(...) #3:
PersonType = "NamelessPerson"

When GetPersonInfo is called for NamelessPerson, the api endpoint would need to make one downstream call:
"GetPersonIdNumber()"

Each of these calls would be populating the same model PersonInfo but all of the fields are nullable in case the downstream call wasn't required for that person type.

Is there a pattern where I can achieve this without duplicating the common downstream calls in every single logic implementation for getting the person info by PersonType.

Below is the initial call

```
public PersonInfo getPersonInfo(int id, PersonType personType) {
        // logic here based on personType to call necessary downstreams and populate person info model
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the poor man's approach would be an if-cascade. :-)

But thinking in design patterns, this looks clearly like a [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Each of your downstreams would define a stragegy, and each PersonType would trigger one or more strategies. We will talk about this many-to-many relationship later on.

Let's start with a strategy interface...

```java
public interface PersonStrategy {

    void enrichPerson(String id, PersonInfo result);

}
```

... and let's have some downstreams implemented as strategies:

```java
public class DefaultStrategy implements PersonStrategy {

    @Override
    public void enrichPerson(String id, PersonInfo result) {
      // fetch basic person data ...
    }
 }

 public class FavoriteToyStrategy implements PersonStrategy {

    @Override
    public void enrichPerson(String id, PersonInfo result) {
      // fetch toys ...
    }

}

public class FavoriteAlcoholicBeverageStrategy implements PersonStrategy {

    @Override
    public void enrichPerson(String id, PersonInfo result) {
      // fetch beverages ...
    }

}
```

Once this is provided, your initial method would look like this:

```java
private final Map<PersonType, List<PersonStrategy>> strategies = new LinkedHashMap<>();

public PersonInfo getPersonInfo(String id, PersonType type) {

    final PersonInfo result = new PersonInfo();
    strategies.get(type).forEach(strategy -> strategy.enrichPerson(id, result));

    return result;
}
```

As you see, I implemented the many-to-many dependency in a multi-value map **with the type as key**. It's not yet populated, I think you can imagine how it works.

Other possibilities:

- have a factory that returns the strategies belonging to a specific
  type.
- have each strategy decide if it reacts to a given type or
  provide a list of types that it belongs to.

As you see: not a single if statement is needed here.